# How Do I Create An Optional Ansible Control Machine With Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

The majority of developers on our project use Windows but our servers are Linux and provisioned with ansible.

In order to test ansible locally we are using Vagrant to create VMs to simulate the servers but we also need to create a VM for ansible as it doesn't support Windows as a control machine.

Some developers use Linux or Macs so they don't need this extra VM.

How do I configure and run Vagrant so that it only provisions this extra VM if I ask it to?

Or alternatively, how do I prevent it provisioning this VM if I tell it not to?

Answer (score 0):

I think some excerpts from [the docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/) can help you:

> Other commands, such as vagrant up, operate on every machine by default. So if you ran vagrant up, Vagrant would bring up both the web and DB machine. **You could also optionally be specific and say `vagrant up web` or `vagrant up db`.**
>
> Additionally, **you can specify a regular expression for matching only certain machines**. This is useful in some cases where you specify many similar machines, for example if you are testing a distributed service you may have a leader machine as well as a follower0, follower1, follower2, etc. **If you want to bring up all the followers but not the leader, you can just do `vagrant up /follower[0-9]/`.** If Vagrant sees a machine name within forward slashes, it assumes you are using a regular expression.

Also, a "primary" machine:

> You can also specify a primary machine. The primary machine will be the default machine used when a specific machine in a multi-machine environment is not specified.
>
> To specify a default machine, just mark it primary when defining it. Only one primary machine may be specified.

You can define one VM as primary, so `vagrant up` will provision only that machine, and you will have to manually pass all other VM names to provision them.

Or you can write some shell script like `up.bat` and `up.sh` and sequentially call `vagrant up VMname` only for those VMs that are required for that OS.